# Discord.net is it possible programmatically add a custom server emoji reaction?

Tags: c#-3.0, discord, discord.net

I'm wondering if there is a way to add a custom, non-standard emoji that belongs to our server.

This works for example:

```
var context = new SocketCommandContext(_client, message as SocketUserMessage);
await context.Message.AddReactionAsync(new Emoji("")).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

But this does not work

```
var context = new SocketCommandContext(_client, message as SocketUserMessage);
await context.Message.AddReactionAsync(new Emoji(":MyCustomEmoji:")).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

**Question**

Is there a way to add a custom emoji that is used on our server? If so please explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Non-standard emojis are managed by the [Emote Class](https://docs.stillu.cc/api/Discord.Emote.html). Here's a [link to the additional documentation](https://docs.stillu.cc/guides/emoji/emoji.html#emote)

> This is directly taken from the documentation of the Emote Class linked above

```cs
public async Task SendAndReactAsync(ISocketMessageChannel channel)
{
    var message = await channel.SendMessageAsync("I am a message.");

    // Creates a Unicode-based emoji based on the Unicode string.
    // This is effectively the same as new Emoji("").
    var heartEmoji = new Emoji("\U0001f495");
    // Reacts to the message with the Emoji.
    await message.AddReactionAsync(heartEmoji);

    // Parses a custom emote based on the provided Discord emote format.
    // Please note that this does not guarantee the existence of
    // the emote.
    var emote = Emote.Parse("<:thonkang:282745590985523200>");
    // Reacts to the message with the Emote.
    await message.AddReactionAsync(emote);
}
```

> A valid Emote format is <:emoteName:emoteId>. This can be obtained by escaping with a \ in front of the emote using the Discord chat client.

Comment: I found it, for future readers. Call `context.Guild.Emotes` to get a list of the Guilds emotes.

Comment: That's all explained in the linked documentation -- "`To obtain the raw string as shown above for your emote, you would need to escape the emote using the escape character \ in chat somewhere.`" the emote format is `<:name:id>`. Note: Context as you allude to only exists within command modules. But yes, you can get a list of emotes for a guild via the SocketGuild entity